# Decrypting an SD Card after the phone is wiped?

Tags: samsung, sd-card, encryption

I have a Samsung Galaxy with an encrypted SD card, but the phone got factory reset.

Is there a way to decrypt it?

Comment: Have you tried decrypting it using the same password that you used to encrypt? Please provide us with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of an encryption is to make it impossible to get access to the data without the correct key.

The encryption key of the SD-card is stored on the device and was deleted by the factory reset.

Therefore the chance to decrypt the sd-card is nearly equal to 0.